# flask postgres dynamic query string with variable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to dynamically query a PostgresSQL table with a variable. For instance, when the user enters a `name`, I want to the user to be redirected to a page that shows table data associated with that `name` (rows from a database table that have that `name` in a specific column). I know I am properly connected to a PostgresSQL database.

In my Flask *app.py* file, I have:

```
@app.route("/test")
def hello():
    html = render_template('test_index.html')
    return html

@app.route("/results")
def goodbye():
    x =  request.args.get('stuff')
    image=sql("SELECT * FROM image WHERE image_id = '%s'" % ({x}))
    html = render_template('test_results.html', target=x, image=image)

    return html
```

In my *test_index.html* template, I have:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<form action="{{url_for('goodbye')}}" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="stuff" value="type something!">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In my *test_results.html* template, I have:

```
 <h1>Image ID:</h1>
 <h2>{{target}}</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Image ID</th>
{% for images in image %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ images.image_id }}</td>
  </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

When I enter a name, I get this error:

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "John"
>       LINE 1: SELECT * FROM image WHERE image_id = 'set([u'John'...

Is there a way to make this method of dynamically querying by string possible?
Or am I approaching this problem in an incorrect manner? (Would I have to declare a model and approach it that way?)

Comment: As you can see by the error message, postgres is thrown off because you're passing a python set as a query. Double check the value of x, it isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Or rather, just use x in your query instead of ({x})

Comment: @Jonas is it because x is a value for a key and not a variable?
I changed the line to `image=sql("SELECT * FROM image WHERE image_id = '%s'" % x)`
but now I get `AssertionError` (`assert type(rawSql)==str`)

Comment: You expect image_id to be a string? What is an example of the value of x? Can you show how `sql` is defined?

Comment: @Jonas It's defined as:
`def sql(rawSql, sqlVars={}):
 assert type(rawSql)==str
 assert type(sqlVars)==dict
 res=db.session.execute(rawSql, sqlVars)
 db.session.commit()
 return res`

Comment: @Jonas image_id is going to be a unique name. "John" is just arbitrary. A real example would be like "Py0515_s15_1_1_1c"

Comment: I see. I think I understand your problem, try my answer and we can take it from there @mrchrisp

Comment: @mrchrisp what library is sql() from? i'm trying to read from a sql database using pandas.read_sql_query and cannot get the variable insertion to work, would like to try out this solution but need to know what library to import. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html

Your approach is spot-on, there's just a small problem in the sql statement in your flask app. Try this instead:

```
@app.route("/test")
def hello():
    html = render_template('test_index.html')
    return html

@app.route("/results")
def goodbye():
    x =  request.args.get('stuff')
    image = sql("SELECT * FROM image WHERE image_id=:image_id_input;", 
        {"image_id_input": x})
    html = render_template('test_results.html', target=x, image=image)

    return html
```

I also assume that you'll want to update your sql query statement to select only the fields of the image that you're interested in displaying. Currently image will be a list of lists, with each inner list being the columns of a matching row.